# Missing required parameters for [Route: serv.update] [URI: serv/{serv}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\izaan\resources\views\serv\create.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting this error but only on the one create.blade.php for serv the rest of the site also use this code and works without any errors

I have tried route{{'serv.update', ['id' => $services]}} as well but still get this error but with all other sections the code works fine and I do not receive this error

The url is also going to the id of item that is clicked but the error then shows up

This is the html create.blade.php

```
   @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="card card-default">
   <div class="card-header">{{isset($services) ? 'Edit Service' : 'Create Service'}}</div>
   <div class="card-body">
       @if($errors->any())
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <ul class="list-group">
               @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
               <li class="list-group-item text-danger">
                   {{$error}}
               </li>
               @endforeach
           </ul>
       </div>
       @endif
       <form action="{{isset($services) ? route('serv.update', ['services'=>$services->id]) : route('serv.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           @csrf
           @if(isset($services))
           @method('PUT')
           @endif
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="title">Title</label>
               <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{isset($services) ? $services->title: ''}}"></input>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="description">Description</label>
               <input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{isset($services) ? $services->description : ''}}"></input>
           </div>


           @if(isset($services))
           <div class="Form-group">
               <img src="{{asset($services->Image)}}" alt="" style="width:150px; height:150px">
           </div>
           @endif
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="image">Image</label>
               <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <button class="btn btn-success">{{isset($services) ? 'Edit Service' : 'Add Service'}}</button>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ServRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ServicesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('serv.index')->with('services', Services::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('serv.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required'
        ]);

        $imageUpload = request()->file('image');
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $imageUpload->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imagePath = public_path('/img/');
        $imageUpload->move($imagePath, $imageName);

        Services::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => '/img/' . $imageName,
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Services created succesfully');

        return redirect(route('serv.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Services $services)
    {
        return view('serv.create')->with('services', $services);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(ServRequest $request, Services $services)
    {

        $data = $request->only(['title', 'description']);


        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->image->store('services');

            Storage::delete($services->image);

            $data['image'] = $image;
        }

        $services->update($data);

        session()->flash('success', 'Post updated succesfully');
        return redirect(route('serv.index'));
    }




    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Services $services)
    {
        $services->delete();

        session()->flash('success', 'Service Deleted succesfully');
        return redirect(route('serv.index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you named your route parameter `'serv'`, try using that as the array index passed to `route`

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it still gives the error I also tried route('serv.update', $services->id) but still get the same error